# attr('height') undefined in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a container div with the following CSS:

```
#container {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

Why does this:

```
alert('height is ' + $("#container").attr('height'));
```

Return that height is undefined?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#container").height()
```

It is due to the height being in the css and not an actual attribute on the html tag.

Answer (score 6):

You probably want to use the [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) or [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) methods.

```
$('#container').css('height')
```

or

```
$('#container').height();
```

depending on what you are trying to do with it.  See the referenced documentation for the differences.

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery.attr` refers to HTML attributes not CSS properties. Use `.css("height")` or mentioned `.height()` method.

More about those methods:

1. [jQuery.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)
2. [jQuery.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
3. [jQuery API Reference](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)